# How to refer different module file in maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

I have a maven project with many modules. One of the module contains xsd files which I want to use in another module. I have gone through many articles but couldn't configure jaxb2-maven-plugin properly to solve below problem.

**Project structure:**

```
Parent
  |
  -------module-x
  |        |
  |         ------- conf
  |                    |
  |                     -- primary-mapping-1.0.xsd 
  |
  ------ module-y
```

**module-y `jaxb2-maven-plugin`**

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                 <execution>
                        <id>xjc2</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>${project.parent.basedir}/module-x/conf</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaFiles>primary-mapping-1.0.xsd</schemaFiles>
                            <packageName>com.xyz.mappings.jaxp</packageName>
                            <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
   <plugin>
```

Build error-

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc (xjc) on project
>   module-y: No schemas have been found -> [Help 1]

How to configure jaxb2-maven-plugin properly to achieve this?

Comment: have you debugged that `${project.parent.basedir}/module-x/conf` resolves correctly ? have you tested with absolute and/or hard coded path ?

Comment: How to debug this what value is getting supplied to this property? are there anyways to run build in debug mode or print properties? Thanks for your response.